# Abp Angular FileUpload with upload progress

Tags: angular, abp, abp.io

There are good community articles out there that explain how to build the `Back-End` side of a file uploader. The gist of it is:

```cs
public async Task<string> UploadFile(IRemoteStreamContent file)
{
    // Save the file to Azure and get the file name
    return fileName;
}
```

But nothing seems to explain how to do `file upload progress` using the `RestService` in `angular`.

Can you please direct me to such a solution?